# Is Client Side Decoration(CSD) dead?

Tags: xorg, window-manager, csd, compositing

As stated by KWin developer Martin: http://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2010/10/kwin-at-uds/

I just wanted someone to confirm it... :-)

Comment: Related on Unix.SE: [What is the story behind Client Side Decorations?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253902)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is. A main compiz developer had previously spoken against it [here](http://smspillaz.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/something-i-should-draw-your-attention-to/), so it's obvious that with him also working on unity, this "feature" would be dropped.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it was officially decided at this UDS that client side windows had too many drawbacks to be worth the benefits. The Unity developers, a compiz developer, and a KWin developer have agreed on a new approach that lets window decorations [paint the background of the window as well as the decorations](http://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2010/10/kwin-at-uds/). Rejoice.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, client side decorations are alive and well in the GNOME side of the pond, and starting with GTK+ 3.12, GTK applications have CSD enabled by default even on non-GNOME window managers.

This is aweful and completely breaks the user experience for non-GNOME users.

Answer (score 1):

### CSD is not dead

Client Side Decorations (CSD) is not dead as this recent 2019 article illustrates:

- [Rhythmbox is Finally Adopting Client Side Decorations](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/01/rhythmbox-is-finally-sorting-its-toolbar-out)

Here are the before and after pictures from the article:

[image: Before and After CSD.png]

As comments below the article point out this is for Gnome and KDE users are left in the dark.